# Safari Quirks Mode: Table takes up entire width of parent.. why?

Tags: css, safari, css-tables, quirks-mode

I am creating a css button using a table.  The button is working fine in Firefox and IE (quirks mode).  Unfortunately there is an issue with Safari's quirks mode.

First a little background.. This is a button for an api, i.e. this button may be used in all sorts of places that I can't control.. so fixing the problem with things like float: left don't really work.  I've tested this in just about every scenario I can imagine, this is the last problem-causer.

The scenario I'm testing this in is a table where a column has align="center".. I can't control that so please don't suggest to change that part.  Only the buttons and css are things I can control.. i.e. the part that begins with `<table cellpadding="0px"...`

The main problem here is that in Safari the button takes up the entire width of its parent, which causes the button next to it to be forced onto the next line.  I need the buttons to appear just as they do in IE and Firefox.

Also, this has to work in IE, Firefox, and Safari and it can't contain a DOCTYPE tag to take it out of quirks mode.

Here is the working example:
[Click me!](http://www.lolstrategies.com/test/button_sample.html)

Any help on why these table buttons are taking up the entire width of the parent table would be very very very much appreciated.

Comment: You can't leave quirks mode? That's heavy, man `:/`

Comment: Why are you using a table for a button?

Comment: Because a span/div button is totally jacked in quirks mode.  Table has been by far the best results I've gotten in quirks mode.

Comment: @Craig Why not use a <button> which you can style too

Comment: @FutureKode
Tried that also actually.  It had a lot of problems with parts of the button floating off and long texts causing it to break etc etc.  I did attempt that route as well tho.  I agree table is certainly not the prettiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

The table button is taking up the entire width of the parent table due to the Quirks mode stylesheet:

- [quirk.css](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/quirks.css)

Use a [CSS filter](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets/Hacks_and_Filters) to make a browser specific exception for Safari.

**References**

- [The table cell width calculation quirk](http://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/)